# How to optimize TikZ code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tkz-fct

What drew me primarily to LaTeX is beautiful typesetting, especially its capability to render mathematical texts and figures beautifully. As a high school teacher, I use LaTeX a lot to create handouts. To draw my figures, I usually use TikZ. I have no experience on coding before LaTeX and so I don't know when my style is already bad or if it is any good at all. What I know is that the code gets the job done.

Now, to get to the question in the title, here is a code that I wrote using TikZ for a topic on limits of functions for high school students.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
        \tkzInit [xmin=-7,xmax=7,ymin=-7,ymax=7]
        \begin{scriptsize}
        \tkzGrid[color = gray!30!white]
        \tkzAxeXY
        \end{scriptsize}
        \draw (-2,3) circle (3pt);
        \fill (1,2) circle (3pt);
        \draw (1,4) circle (3pt);
        \fill (-2,4) circle (3pt);
        \fill (7,-1) circle (3pt);
        \draw [-latex] (-2.1,2.9) parabola (-4.9,-7);
        \draw (1,2) parabola (-1.9,2.9);
        \draw [-latex] (1.1,3.9) parabola (2.9,-7);
        \draw [-latex] (7,-1) parabola (3.1,7);
        \draw [dashed = on 3pt off 3pt] (-5,-7) -- (-5,7);
        \draw [dashed = on 3pt off 3pt] (3,-7) -- (3,7);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is supposed to be a graph of a function $f$ with the following properties:

- `\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow -5^+} f(x) = -\infty$` (My use of `\limits` here is how I really use it in my handouts and test papers since it makes the math easier to read by my high school students)
- `\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow -2^-} f(x) = 3$`
- `\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 1^+} f(x) = 4$`
- `\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 3^-} f(x) =-\infty$`
- `\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow 3^+} f(x) = +\infty$`

Note that I used a lot of parabola in my TikZ code, though I just used them because it made my code shorter and so saved me a lot of encoding time and doing manual computations (which I could then use for tutoring students having difficulty with calculus) for the placement of nodes/coordinates. (Also, I have little patience at this point with bezier curves. I know, I really have to change this behavior soon.) But note that in the actual PDF, there is a space between the hole at (-2,3) and the curves connected to it. So my first question really is:

**How do I create a curve with one end a hole?** I have once tried something like `\draw [o-] (-2,3) -- (1,2);` but I end up with an awkward-looking figure.

Also, as you can see, I have mixed TikZ code using some syntax from the standard TikZ and @Altermundus 's `tkz-fct` (which I think is just okay since the package `tkz-fct` is built on top of TikZ). Again, my main reason is practicality, attaining my goal without using several `foreach` loops. So my second question is, is this okay, sound LaTeX coding?

Comment: **Unrelated:** I looked at your blog and found some of the images scanned into a tex file. So, I thought I'll point you to a link that might probably help you. [this one in particular](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47532/lower-and-upper-riemann-sums) Search around the site and our Tikz experts would have written about most of your doubts.

Comment: As for this question, I don't see the question distinctly but it might just be me. But, I'd suggest that you rewrite your question to make the question explicit.

Comment: @KannappanSampath, one of my questions concern cases when one has a discontinuity in the graph like say a function defined by $f(x)=\frac{x-1}{(x-1)(x+2)}$. This one has a _hole_ (discontinuity) at (1,1/3). Once, I tried doing an import from Geogebra but the discontinuity was not shown in the figure. Drawing a circle centered at (1,1/3) will just give a circle on top of the $f(x) = 1/(x+2)$ at $x=1$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here the code with only `tkz-fct`. It's possible to use only tikz or the excellent `pgfplots`.

Some strange problems appears with gnuplot, it's why you can see sometimes (-5) instead of -5 or (-1)*(x-1)**2 instead of -1(x-1)**2.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-fct}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5,font=\scriptsize]
        \tkzInit [xmin=-7,xmax=7,ymin=-7,ymax=7]
        \tkzGrid[color = gray!30!white] 
        \tkzVLines[dashed = on 3pt off 3pt,color=blue]{(-5),3}
        \tkzAxeXY
        \tkzFct[domain=-4.8:-2,<-]{-1.2*(x+2)**2+3}
        \tkzFct[domain=-2:1]{(x-1)**2/9+2}
        \tkzFct[domain=1:2.6,->]{(-1)*(x-1)**2/0.25+4}
        \tkzDefPointByFct[with=b](-2)  
        \tkzDrawPoint[fill=white](tkzPointResult)
        \tkzDefPointByFct[draw,with=b](1)
        \tkzDefPointByFct[with=c](1) 
        \tkzDrawPoint[fill=white](tkzPointResult)
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have some manual for this package? it seems very useful to me but I can't find the manual. I can read french if needed

Comment: Thank you very much for the speedy reply @Altermundus. Great. This helps a lot. Although I would still like to know your opinion about the mixed syntaxes.

Comment: It's  possible to mix the syntaxes but I prefer to avoid the mix when it's  possible.

Comment: @leo sorry for the moment the manual is only in french but there are a lot of examples.

Comment: And where is the french manual? :)

Comment: In the terminal, types `texdoc tkz-fct` or you can find the file here : `texlive/2012/texmf-dist/doc/latex/tkz-fct/tkz-fct-screen.pdf`

Comment: Leo! Learn how to use PGFplots! ^^