# Lower and upper Riemann sums with the help of pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

In this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47532/lower-and-upper-riemann-sums) we have the following code

```
    \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks-add}
\begin{document}

\psset{plotpoints=200,algebraic}
\begin{pspicture}(-0.5,-2.5)(10,3)
\psStep[linecolor=magenta,StepType=upper,
  fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=cyan!50](0,9){20}{sqrt(x)*sin(x)}
\psStep[linecolor=blue,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=blue!30,
  opacity=0.4](0,9){20}{sqrt(x)*sin(x)}
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle]{->}(0,0)(0,-2.25)(10,3)
\psplot[linewidth=1.5pt]{0}{10}{sqrt(x)*sin(x)}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

It produces the following figure

[image]

the first one. It uses , however, PSTRICKS that has to be run with XeLaTeX or with some additional configuration in PDFLATEX. Since I don't want to include pstricks code in my document could someone help me convert the code to pgfplot?

I am not confortable in using pgfplot myself! THank you.

Comment: There are several `pgfplots` answers in the linked question. Can't you use those?

Comment: I'm particurarly interested in the first figure.. It's for the book I'm writing and it depicts the matter the best way possible... :)

Comment: If you write a book, probably the best thing is to have all your images as pdf, else the compilation could be very slow. So using `pstricks` inside `standalone` document compiled with `xelatex` is not a bad thing, no ?

Comment: Since I want the document to be portable when sent to my colleague for corrections etc I don't want to have to worry about sending all images along with the pdf... Maybe something goes wrong ... !! This case is at the back of myhead. 

That is why I want all figures to be in code format using only tikz, pgfplots...

Comment: @Kpym Also, by inserting images I increase the size of the document. The printer wants me to send him a document less than 3MG... the document is already 1.6 MB

Comment: Compiling with `xelatex` produce often smaller file.

Comment: @Kpym Sure, it does... but I don't use `XeLaTeX` ... I don't know how to use it. Sorry.!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{declare function={f(\x)=sqrt(\x)*sin(deg(\x));}}
\xdef\LstMain{(0,0)}
\xdef\LstPlus{(0,0)}
\xdef\LstMinus{(0,0)}
\foreach \X in {1,...,20}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{\X*9/20}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{f(\X)}
\xdef\LstMain{\LstMain (\myx,\myy)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{(\X-1)*9/20}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myyplus}{max(f(\X),0)}
\xdef\LstPlus{\LstPlus (\myx,\myyplus)}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{(\X-1)*9/20}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myyminus}{min(f(\X),0)}
\xdef\LstMinus{\LstMinus (\myx,\myyminus)}
}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{21*9/20}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myyplus}{max(f(21),0)}
\xdef\LstPlus{\LstPlus (\myx,\myyplus)}
\typeout{\LstMinus}
\pgfplotsset{every linear axis/.append style={ymin=-4.5,ymax=4.5,xmin=0,xmax=9.5,axis lines=center}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar, xtick={2,4},
        xticklabels={$a$,$b$},axis on top]
\addplot[ybar interval,fill=red,opacity=0.15] coordinates \LstPlus;
\addplot[ybar interval,fill=green,opacity=0.15] coordinates \LstMinus;
\addplot[ybar interval,fill=blue!20] coordinates \LstMain;
\end{axis}
\begin{axis}[axis x line=none,axis y line=none]
\addplot[domain=0:9,no marks,samples=100,thick] {f(x*20/9)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Quick question: If I'd like to replace 2 and 4 with a and b respectively and remove the coordinates from the y axis what would be the change of the code?

Comment: @Tolaso I updated my answer.